# Java code for exam

Tags: java, disk-cleanup

```
import java.io.*;

class B_13
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws
  Antifundamentalist,UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
    File file = new File("/rr");
    String[] myFiles;
    int count = 0;
    if(file.isDirectory())
    {
      myFiles=file.list();
      for(int i=0;i<myFiles.length;i++)
      {
        File myFile = new File(file,myFiles[i]);
        if(myFile.delete())
        {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  System.out.println(count+ " : Files & Directories are deleted");
  }
}
```

I am having this code for my exams tommorow,this is a program to cleanup task.

this programs runs normally, it says "0 files and directories deleted"

I want to know,where does it looks for files and from where does it delete files ? where we add location or path in the program ?

I tried changing this `File file = new File("/rr");` I made an `rr` folder in home directory and added some files but it did not delete those either.

Comment: BTW it's java and not javascript

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it si about fixing Java code and not *nix.

Comment: i am running this code on ubuntu linux and the code related to linux .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It opens `/rr` that is sitting in the root. If you created an `rr` directory in your home directory then change the name to where that is located. eg "/home/your_user_name/rr"

Comment: Thanks a lot,it is working now.i forgot to add username in the path.